# C++ ADT Comparison without using ==

Tags: c++

For an assignment i'm writing a Map Class and as part of this class i have a find function that searches the map based on a key and returns the corresponding value. However, using == will lose me marks as it may cause issues with certain data types. The map class is using templates to generic, however i can't figure out how to make it work without using ==. Also, if they key can't be found in the map what is the best way to inform the user? The data structure behind the map has to be an array as specified in the assignment brief and can't use any of the STL.

Current find method.

```
template <typename T, typename S>
S Map<T, S>::find(T key)
{

        int i = 0;
        bool found = false;
        int index;
        while (i < mapSize - 1 && !found)
        {
            if (mapArray[i].key == key)
            {
                found = true;
                index = i;
            }

            i++;
        }

        if (found)
        {
            return mapArray[index].value;
        }
        else
        {
            return NULL;
        }


}
```

Comment: You can still borrow ideas from [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), even if you can't use it. You can template on a comparison functor, and even have it default to something using `==`. Consider using [*iterators*](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/16-3-stl-iterators-overview/) to indicate positions of elements in the map. Then use an "end" iterator, to indicate "not found".

Comment: No offence, but I think you'll be losing marks on the efficiency tests. A linear search is hardly the fastest way to look for an item in a map.

Comment: This is some heavy spaghetti. Consider using [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), or at least a [range-based `for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). You should also return directly from inside the loop instead of juggling `found` and `index` around.

Comment: You also have a bug. If you search for the last element you won't find it. You can use either `while (i < mapSize && !found)` or `while (i <= mapSize - 1 && !found)` or even replace your while loop with a for loop `for (int i = 0; i < mapSize - 1; i++) {if (mapArray[i].key == key){ ...; break; }}`

Comment: @SimonKraemer Yes and the same happens when the map has only 1 element. `while (0 < 1 - 1 && ..)`

Comment: The mapSize -1 issue you highlighted is fine for now and i know about it but it works it's due to something else. I need to go through and change it to not need -1 basically.

Comment: @BoBTFish Is there anywhere i can look into going about implementing iterators in my class.